# How do I extract IP addresses and port numbers from this string?

Tags: php, arrays

I need to parse an array of proxies with their IP and port from the output of a `textarea` element, with PHP. I'm wondering what is the most efficient approach to this problem as the lists uploaded via the `textarea` could be in `proxy:port`, or `proxy port` (with a space), in both cases each proxy would be seperated by a line break.

For example, if the following lists were uploaded on two different occassions:

```
34.345.32.1 9032
4.3.21.234 2023
45.31.45.324 1025
```

And

```
34.345.32.1:9032
4.3.21.234:2023
45.31.45.324:1025
```

Then the resulting array in both cases would be

```
$proxies = array (
  array('34.345.32.1',9032),
  array('4.3.21.234',2023),
  array('45.31.45.324',1025)
);
```

I've tried the following code, however on `var_dump()` of either `array` nothing is printed.

```
$array = explode("\n", $_POST['proxies']);
$array2 = explode(" " $array);
```

Comment: what have you tried? we can help you solve your problem once we see that you have put effort towards a solution.

Comment: @cmorrissey I've tried http://pastie.org/10266747

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple `foreach` to loop through your array and `strpos` to detect the delimiter

```
$proxies = explode("\n", $_POST['proxies']);
foreach($proxies as $key => $value){
    if(strpos($value, ' ')){
        $proxies[$key] = explode(' ', $value);  
    } else {
        $proxies[$key] = explode(':', $value);  
    }
}

print_r($proxies);
```

This is a basic example you will need to expand on this to make sure your data is normalized beyond this point.

Answer (score 0):

To validate proxy I am using this function on my production sites.

```
    /**
     * Validate IP and PORT | This will give you array of proxy into IP and PORT
     * Valid IP Address (0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.255): Valid port (1-65535)
     *  IP = $matches[1]
     *  PORT = $matches[2]
     * @return boolean|array
     */
    public function proxyIpPort($proxy)
    {
        try {
            //Valid IP Address (0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.255): Valid port (1-65535)
            if (preg_match('~\b([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}):([0-9]{1,10}\b)~', $proxy, $matches)) {

                //if port range doesnot match return error
                if (!preg_match('/^([0-9]{1,4}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])$/m', $matches[2], $arraystr)) {
                    return array(
                        'success' => false,
                        'error' => 'Invalid Port Range',
                        'ip' => $matches[1],
                        'port' => $matches[2],
                    );
                }

                if (filter_var($matches[1], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV4) === false) {
                    return array(
                        'success' => false,
                        'error' => 'Invalid IP Address',
                        'ip' => $matches[1],
                        'port' => $matches[2],
                    );
                }

                if (filter_var($matches[1], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE) === false) {
                    return array(
                        'success' => false,
                        'error' => 'Private IP provided',
                        'ip' => $matches[1],
                        'port' => $matches[2],
                    );
                }

                if (filter_var($matches[1], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE) === false) {
                    return array(
                        'success' => false,
                        'error' => 'Reserve IP provided',
                        'ip' => $matches[1],
                        'port' => $matches[2],
                    );
                }

                //all verifications done
                return array(
                    'success' => true,
                    'ip' => $matches[1],
                    'port' => $matches[2],
                );
            }

            //all validations failed return invalid ip
            return array(
                'success' => false,
                'error' => 'Invalid IP:PORT'
            );
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            return array(
                'success' => false,
                'error' => $th,
            );
        }
    }
```

This function will give you exact validation for public proxies.

About the proxies with no `:` use

```
$txt = "34.345.32.1 9032
4.3.21.234 2023
45.31.45.324 1025";

$proxies = str_replace(" ", ":", $txt); //replace the empty space between ip and port with `:`
$proxies = str_replace("\n", ",", $proxies); // replace the new line `\n` with `,` to convert text into array
$proxies_array = explode(",", $proxies);
print_r($proxies_array);
```

use given proxies array and use foreach to test every single proxy one by one

Comment: previous answers were given in fast this is a complete one that I use in my proxy script.

Answer (score 0):

This task receives user-supplied input (textarea), then endeavors to parse strings with slight variability.  This is a good candidate for a regex function.

One way which delivers your exact desired output with a concise pattern is: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/lJj5e))

```
preg_match_all('~(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})[: ]\K\d{4}~', $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

var_export(array_map('array_reverse', $matches));
```

The above is capturing the proxy substring, then matching the varying delimiter, then forgetting those matched characters then matching the port substring as the "fullstring match".  In doing so, the `$matches` array has the subarray elements in reverse order -- you can call `array_reverse()` on each subarray if the order is critical.

Otherwise, you could be less fancy and just capture the proxy and port substrings and tolerate the unwanted fullstring match. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/XbXEX))

```
preg_match_all('~(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})[: ](\d{4})~', $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

var_export($matches);  // just access the [1] and [2] subarray values
```

---

I find a double-explode() technique to be less attractive for this task, because as I stated earlier, this is user-supplied data and that must not be trusted.

If I was going to use a non-regex solution (that offers no validation), I would use something D.R.Y.:

```
$proxies = [];
foreach (explode("\n", $_POST['proxies']) as $line) {
    $proxies[] = explode(
        strpos($value, ':') ? ':' : ' ',
        $value
    );
}
```